# How to backup git stash content?

Tags: git

- I have pending uncommitted works
- I need to switch to another branch for some urgent work
- As my current Work in Progress is not finished, I don't want to commit it. I use  `git stash` to put it aside.

Additionally, I would like to backup that stash content on a shared drive. Just for safety. What is an elegant solution to archive the stash content on file?

Answer (score 52, accepted):

You can get the diff by running show command:

```
git stash show -p > stash.diff
```

This is the diff file which you can use as a backup.

Later you can apply the diff to the existing repository:

```
git apply stash.diff
# and potentially stash again:
git stash
```

Comment: @Zbynek `git stash show` merely says "MyProject/MyFile.scala | 34 +++++"  1 file changed, 34 insertions(+). If I backup this "status report" (which is captured in stash.diff as per your instruction). Then let's assume my hard drive has trouble after I amde the backup. How does stash.diff know about the actual content of the 34 lines I wrote INSIDE the MyFile.scala file?

Comment: @Polymerase : Sorry, I missed the `-p` (which is default for `diff` but not for `stash`). Answer updated.

Comment: @ZbynekVyskovsky-kvr000 Oh wow that `-p` option is really cool. You have answered exactly what I asked in my initial question.

Comment: Nice! In my case I was getting the "unrecongnized input" in PowerShell, which could not resolve by using Git Bash. So I copied the content from stash.diff to a newly created stashN.diff and used it instead

Answer (score 9):

> I don't want to commit it

Actually, `git stash` operates by making two commits (sometimes) three, so if you stashed your work, you committed perhaps without even knowing it.  But there is nothing wrong most of the time with making a temporary commit.  Just add your current work, and then make a temporary commit via:

```
git commit -m 'WIP'
```

Then, you can push your branch out to the repository, and that should serve as a backup.  When you return to finish the work, you can amend that temporary commit via:

```
git commit --amend
```

Feel free to change the message to something more meaningful, but in any case the `WIP` message can serve as a reminder.

If the branch you are working on could be shared by others, then you could push your branch with the temporary commit to a different location as a backup, e.g.

```
git push origin local_branch:some_other_location
```

Comment: +1 for `git commit --amend`, @Tim, is there like a temporary that can be shared across something like email and apply on another machine and commit ?

Comment: @VinayVeluri Look at the other answer which appears to address this.  In any case, you can always share branches, hence a temporary commit can be shared just as any other commit.

Comment: gotcha, this is what we usually do, checking if we have another way.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Your answer is very nice thx. Hope you don't mind I set Zbynek's answer as official because his answer is exactly what was asked in the OP.

Answer (score 4):

As [Tim Biegeleisen](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42358589/86072) said, `git stash` actually creates a commit - it just doesn't move any of your branches around.

You can access your last stashed content through `stash@{0}` (the second to last through `stash@{1}`, etc ... `git stash list` to view a full list of what you can access).

The most straightforward way I see to make a stash more persistent is : create a new branch :

```
$ git branch wip/adding/new/feature stash@{0}
```

Now, with a branch pointing at it, this stashed content will not expire, will be transmitted when you clone or fetch from this repo, etc ...

The simplest way to backup a repo is to clone it :

```
$ cd path/to/external/drive
$ git clone my/repo

# you can then update your backup by running :
$ git fetch         # from the clone
```

this will save all branches and tags defined in your original repo.

Comment: thanks but this is overkill just to save a temporary work for a short period. The stash content may be 1K. Backing up a whole repo could be 1 million times bigger. Sorry for my novice way of doing, but I think it is still simpler to just commit my temp work and undo it later.

Answer (score 4):

extending Zybnek's answer.

If you want to backup all of your stashes without making a commit or creating a temp branch:

1. To count no of stashes  `git stash list | wc -l`
2. execute `for i in {0..n}; do $(git stash show -p stash@{$i} > stash_$i.diff); done`

Answer (score 2):

I managed to backup a stash by doing this (files and paths used by Git Extensions):

- copy the "stash" file located at git\refs
- copy the "stash" file located at git\logs\refs
- copy all the folders from git\objects (except folders "info" and "pack")

To recover the files, copy the files you once backed up back into the folders mentioned above. After that, the stash will be available for you to use through Git Extensions.

Comment: Could you provide details as to how to recover from the copies?

Comment: Hi @tjheslin1. To back up the files you follow the steps above, to recover the files do it the other way around: get the files/folders you had backed up and copy them once again to the paths inside the git folders mentioned above... Not sure this is what you referred to, if not let me know with some more information or an example of what you intend to do and I'll do my best to answer accordingly... Best.

Comment: In my case doing it this way transferred only the last 5 stashes. To copy all of them I had to copy the whole .git folder.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution is to clone the repo another time to another place on disk, e.g. `/tmp`.
This way, you tick all boxes above, and you won't have to stash anything.

Best of both worlds.